# allow hotlink from your domain and other domains with a string or parament

Tags: .htaccess

So lost on how to get this done ... any advice would be appreciated.

I'd like to setup htaccess to allow hotlinking from my personal domain and some third party domains based on their url string/parameters.

So allow from my domain all files , images etc...

```
https://example.com/
```

also allow for some specific domains based on the string or parameter , so in the example below i want to allow hotlinking for any domain that has index of / string / parameter of "10065" and "44265"

```
https://thirdpartysite.com/home/10065
https://thirdpartysite2.com/2021/options?L=10065&O=07

https://thirdpartysite3.com/home/44265
https://thirdpartysite4.com/2021/options?L=44265&O=07
```

All other sites not listed above to be blocked.

Any ideas on how this could be done ?

Comment: "has index of / string / parameter of "10065" and "44265"" - do you mean any URL that contains either of these numbers in the URL-path or query string? Have you confirmed that these _third party sites_ are setting the appropriate Referrer-Policy and not suppressing the _referrer_? The "problem" here is that if these are arbitrary 3rd party sites then the _default_ Referrer-Policy in modern browsers (strict-origin-when-cross-origin) suppresses the URL-path and query string, so what you are wanting to do may not be possible.

Comment: Yes that is what I mean , any and all urls that have those 2 as part of the url or parameter. Yes and confirmed the sites do not suppress the url path